JQL for swimlanes group by stories relates to Tasks
I want to setup my sprint board using JQL that groups by Stories with related tasks and bugs.
Currently I am using JQL Search Extensions plugin and used the following filter.
issueLinkType in ("relates to") and issuetype = Task and Sprint in openSprints()
It actually shows all the Stories under team name but not the story. I changed the query to below one now al the stories completely disappeared but still display group by Filter name instead of story and Everything Else
issueLinkType in ("relates to") and issuetype = Task and Sprint in openSprints()
Any solution? Not sure I am using the right function
